# How to release Flutter WearOS App to Play Store

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, wear-os

I built a flutter app that is primarily targeting WearOS but works on all Android devices.

It is running perfectly fine on the emulator and I can publish it on the Playstore for testing. However, when I want to mark it as a WearOS App Release Type, I am prompted to upload a WearOS appbundle, so my app bundle is not recognized as being runnable on WearOS.

What do I need to change in order for the Play Store to accept my appbundle as a WearOS app?

When listing supported devices of my release on the Playstore I get this:
[image: When listing supported devices of my release on the Playstore I get this]

Edit: I was able to deploy as WearOS app only using the following line in the Manifest, but would like to make it available to all devices:

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```

Comment: Check this: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-building-wearos-app-fedf0f06d1b4

Comment: I've read this post before, it only describes how to deploy a WearOS app only. I would like to deploy mine standalone on both WearOS and any other Android Device

Answer (score 0):

You should click on "add filter" and choose device type = wearable, don't use the search bar since it filters the model name and many devices do not use "wear" as their name:

[image]